# Expected area of the intersection of of triangles made up random points inside a circle, all the triangles must contain the origin

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

How to find the expected area of the intersection of a set of triangles made up $N$ random points that are picked uniformly inside a circle? The triangles must contain the origin of the circle. If none of the trinagles contain the rigin we pick again $N$ random points until at least one triangle contain the origin and calculate the expected intersection area of all the triangles that contain the origin.

Comment: Is that really supposed to be a question mark at the end or do you impose the condition that each triangle of the set contains the origin (i.e you reject those obtained from picking vertices unifomly with respect to area that fail to contain the origin)? And how big is your set of triangles?

Comment: sorry, it is a condition, I pick N random points inside a circle and I want to calculate the expected area of the intersection of all the triangles made by these points and contain the origin. It is clear now?

Comment: @Noureddine: Unfortunately it isn't. You pick $N$ points inside a circle and consider all $\binom N3$ triangles they form. Then do you check whether all those triangles contain the origin, and pick again if they don't? Or do you use only those triangles that do contain the origin and consider their intersection? In the latter case, do you pick again if *none* of the triangles contain the origin?

Comment: Or in that last case, do you then consider the empty intersection, i.e. the entire circle?

Comment: I do not pick again, from the N points I construct all possible triangles and I keep only the triangles that contain the origin for the intersection. I want to calculate the expected area of the intersection region. For example, for 4 points there are four possible triangles. and if one triangle contains the origin there is only one other triangle that contain the origin from the remaining three triangles.

Comment: I think that I should not consider the case where none of the triangles contains the origin, if none of the triangles contain the origin I repeat the experience.

Comment: @Noureddine: OK, that was a misunderstanding then. By "picking again", I meant exactly what I think you mean by "I repeat the experience". (By the way, that should be "experiment"; it's the same word in French but not in English.) Please clarify the question itself so that people don't have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @Noureddine: I provided an answer for $N=3$. For the general case, please explain why you believe that the problem should be tractable. What's the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer for $N=3$, along with some thoughts on the general problem.

By ordering the points by angle and arbitrarily fixing the angle of the first point at $0$, the expected area of a triangle containing the origin can be obtained as

$$
\frac{\displaystyle3\int\mathrm d\triangle\frac12r_1r_2\sin\phi_2}{\displaystyle\int\mathrm d\triangle}\;,
$$

where the integrand in the numerator is the area of the triangle formed by the origin and the first two points, whose integral is by symmetry equal to that of the areas of the triangles formed by the origin with the other two pairs of points (hence the factor $3$), and where

$$
\int\mathrm d\triangle=
\int_0^\pi\mathrm d\phi_2\int_{\pi}^{\phi_2+\pi}\mathrm d\phi_3\int_0^1\mathrm dr_1r_1\int_0^1\mathrm dr_2r_2\int_0^1\mathrm dr_3r_3
$$

integrates over the polar coordinates for which the origin is contained in the triangle. The radial integrations yield $\left(\frac13\right)^2\cdot\frac12$ in the numerator and $\left(\frac12\right)^3$ in the denominator, so this is

$$
\begin{align}
&
\frac23\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\mathrm d\phi_2\int_{\pi}^{\phi_2+\pi}\mathrm d\phi_3\sin\phi_2}{\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\mathrm d\phi_2\int_{\pi}^{\phi_2+\pi}\mathrm d\phi_3}
\\
=&
\frac23\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\mathrm d\phi_2\phi_2\sin\phi_2}{\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\mathrm d\phi_2\phi_2}
\\
=&
\frac23\frac\pi{\frac12\pi^2}
\\
=&
\frac4{3\pi}
\approx
0.4244\;.
\end{align}
$$

This is to be compared to the average area $\dfrac{35}{48\pi}\approx0.2321$ without the condition that the triangle contains the origin (which is slightly more difficult to calculate).

The problem for general $N$ can be reformulated as finding the probability that none of the segments joining $N$ random points whose convex hull contains the origin lies between a further random point and the origin. What makes this seem difficult is the fact that the events for the various segments aren't independent.

Numerical simulations indicate that the answer for $N=4$ might be $\dfrac9{10\pi}$.

Comment: Thanks, yes my simulation results for $N=4$ are very close to $9/10 \pi$. Could you please give us more detail about the answare for the case $N=3$ and how we can generalize it for $n=4$.

Comment: @Noureddine: It seems rather intractable to generalize it for $n=4$ -- I'm not really inclined to give it more thought than I already have unless you explain why you believe it might be tractable. As for the $N=3$ case, what part would you like more details on? I tried to spell the calculation out in full.

Comment: What do you mean by tractable?

Comment: @Noureddine: Capable of being solved without astronomical effort. Quite generally, it's a good idea to say something about the source and context of your questions to give people an idea what to expect. If you just put a question out there without context, there's no way of knowing whether it's easy, hard or perhaps completely unsolvable; whereas for instance if it's from a textbook or an exam or a contest, that gives some indication of the level of difficulty to expect, and some confidence that it's actually possible to solve it.